# This code won't replace the diacritics I entered

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

```cs
public string FaraDiacritice(string x)
    {
        return x.Replace("ă", "a").Replace("î", "i").Replace("â", "a").Replace("ș", "s").Replace("ț", "t");
    }
```

I'm using Unity and Visual Studio Comunity 2022, maybe it does not support unicode characters somehow. Even if

```cs
        Debug.Log(FaraDiacritice("ăîâșț"));
```

works

[image: Debug Log in Unity saying aiast]

I am using it in this context:

```cs
A1.text = FaraDiacritice(TextScript.instance.GetAnswer(Raspunsuri.instance.Q6[1]));
```

I don't want all the diacritics changed, even though I know thats posible, I just want to fix **my** code.

Comment: I don't understand ... so if `Debug.Log(FaraDiacritice("ăîâșț"));` works correctly ... then what doesn't? What exactly is the content of `TextScript.instance.GetAnswer(Raspunsuri.instance.Q6[1])` ?

Comment: @derHugo I set a textmeshpro text to that and Q1-Q6 are lists of answers

Comment: yeah .. but what is the content exactly? I guess it just doesn't match exactly with the same characters ... As an off-topic side note, avoid using those singletons